# The model backing the context has changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seen the other answers but I can't get this to work.  I have a simple, clean website with two models:

Blog Model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Blog

    Public Property BlogId() As Integer

    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Description() As String
    Public Property DateCreated As Date

    Public Overridable Property Articles() As ICollection(Of Article)

End Class

Public Class BlogDbContext

    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Blogs As DbSet(Of Blog)

End Class
```

Article Model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Imports GemcoBlog

Public Class Article

    Public Property ArticleId() As Integer
    Public Property BlogId() As Integer
    Public Property Title() As String
    Public Property Body() As String
    Public Property DateCreated As Date

Public Overridable Property Blog() As Blog

End Class

Public Class ArticleDbContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Articles As DbSet(Of Article)
    Public Property Blogs As DbSet(Of Blog)
End Class
```

When I add controllers which creates the controllers and views, then run, I get this error:

> The model backing the 'ArticleDbContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or
>   call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance.
>   For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will
>   automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it
>   with new data.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12:  Line 13:         Function Index() As ViewResult Line 14:
>   Dim articles = db.Articles.Include(Function(a) a.Blog) Line 15:
>   Return View(articles.ToList()) Line 16:         End Function
>
> Source File: C:\Users\darchual\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Blog\Blog\Controllers\ArticleController.vb
>   Line: 14

How can I fix this error?

Edit:

I fixed this by removing the EdmMetaData table from the database.  Do I need this table?  Is it good for anything?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest you 2 possible ways to fix the issue. What happened when you tried them?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.  I edited the question by saying, "I fixed this by removing the EdmMetaData table from the database. Do I need this table? Is it good for anything?"

Comment: EdmMetaData is used by the Entity Framework to verify that the current model matches the database. Deleting it makes EF think everything is up to date, so it won't be able to detect future changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue for me was to delete the EdmMetaData table from the database.

Comment: How?, Please elaborate fully. This issue, it seems, is also confused by different EF versions.

Comment: I deleted the table from the database by right clicking it and clicking delete.  I no longer use CodeFirst method, I just create the database then write a model to reflect it.